# JavaScript Markup Editor using selection and range object

Tags: javascript, editor, selection, range, markup

I am trying to write a JavaScript based Markup Editor (WYSIWIG) using the selection and the range object. I have no problems so far to access these objects.

My problems begin here:

Using the range object, I can access its properties startContainer/StartOffset and EndContainer/Endoffset. That means I get back the information about the node my selection starts in including the internal position and the same information about the end of the selection.

As far as I have understood, JavaScript automatically adds starting or ending tags in case my selection breaks existing tree structures.

If I want to add some markup now, how can I deal with these broken structures?

Example:

```
This <i>is my</i><b>sample</b> text.
```

Now I would like to underline the part "my sample"

That means something like this has to be constructed out of the selection of "my sample":

```
This <i>is <u>my</u></i><b><u>sample</u></b> text.
```

But since I do not notice the breaking of a prexisting tree structure, how can I do this? How can I ensure valid markup?

I was also thinking about processing the whole string, but I do not know about the global positions of letters/text but only about their position within certain nodes.

I hope this question is clear and I apologize for its general form. But I am really getting crazy about this stuff ...

Answer (score 0):

There is the built-in method `document.execCommand()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands)), which handles this stuff for you. In the case of underline, it would be

```
document.execCommand("Underline", false, null);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3NcEP/

Note that this only works on editable content (using `contenteditable` or `designMode`) in most browsers.

If you need to apply some styling to the selection that isn't provided by one of the built-in commands, you'll need to handle all the nodes within the selection yourself, splitting if necessary at each end of the selection. This is non-trivial. Also, IE < 9 does not support [DOM Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) and `Selection` and does things completely differently. If you need to handle these browsers, a library like such as my own [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot fo the answer. I do not care about IE compatibility but I fear that I will have to go the non-trivial way ... I need a possibility to insert spans with arbitrary classes. Is there an existing editor which could inspire me? Or do the algorithms exist somewhere?

Comment: @Tobi: Have a look at the CSS class applier module in Rangy: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule

Comment: this css applier module looks interesting! First I have another problem to deal with: now I have thought about finding out if a selection breaks a preexisting tree tructure by comparing range.startContainer and range.endContainer. If true, sel is within the same node, so noth. is broken and a new node can be inserted within this. If false, the selection crosses a preexisting tree structure. I have recognized that this detection does not really work constantly: sometimes it is true, sometimes not, although I always select the same node. Is there a diff. between mouse and keyboard sel.?

Comment: @Tobi: How browsers represent selections does vary, but I'm not sure that's relevant to this problem. The steps needed for detecting whether a range can be surrounded or not are well defined in the DOM Range spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level-2-Range-Surrounding. If you're using Rangy, you can use the range's `canSurroundContents()` method.